# Multiple smoke flows in one domain, with different colors

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

So I want to mix smoke with different colors in one domain object, I've found tutorials about that topic with Blender render engine, but not how to do that effect in cycles. I can define the smoke color in the node setup of the domain, but how can i seperate between my different flow objects?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use an *Attribute* node with *color* as a keyword to read color information from smoke (use colored flow objects).
Available keywords are:

- color
- density
- flame
- heat *
- velocity *

They are now all defined in `/addons/cycles/kernel/kernel_types.h` though dunno if the last 2 are yet usable (maybe in some test builds) - **edit** - these attributes are usable from version 2.78 up - from left to right: smoke render, heat map, velocity vectors:

[image]

Smoke sim from [benu](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?322427-Cycles-Volumetric-Rendering&p=2625031&viewfull=1#post2625031):

[image]

Comment: Cool to see heat is now available!!!