# Heat distortion effect in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing, materials

How could I go about creating a heat distortion effect behind a jet in cycles? This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: maybe this is valuable for you ? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23802/multiple-smoke-flows-in-one-domain-with-different-colors/23803#23803