# Multiple Colors Flame + Smoke 1 Domain

Tags: rendering, physics, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation, fire

[image]Is it possible to have multiple objects that are emitting Flame and Smoke have different colored flame and smoke within the same domain?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23802/multiple-smoke-flows-in-one-domain-with-different-colors?rq=1

Comment: @vklidu - Thank you but this is one object with multiple colors. I want like multiple objects each with a different color.

Object 1 - Blue
Object 2 - Red
Object 3 - Green etc..

Comment: No, it is exactly what are you asking for ... But I agree it is not explained well ... So check my answer if that brought light into your question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Smoke

*Speaking to smoke – I can only extend already my provided link in comment (or Zargul's answer) by more screens ...*

---

[image]

For *Domain* object type in **Color Attribute** field **color**

[image]

... or use **Atribute node** if you are not using *Principled Volume* node.

[image]

For each smoke emitter (Cube) change under *Physics Properties > Fluid > Smoke Color*

[image]

### Flame

I'm not sure if there is a way to mix flames inside one domain. From provided image (where flames seems to be in just vertical direction without touch), you can fake it by masking half of domain for flames data and merge them back together in single material.

[image]
[image]

Since this is a fake ... don't let flames pass a center of the domain ... It will break the illusion ;)

[image]

Note: Not directly suggested ... but once I tried to use multiple domains https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/246353861 that worked surprisingly well :) Tested especially for a long smoke trials where you quickly loose resolution since domain resolution is based on number of divisions along longest side of domain. So in some specific smoke trails it was impossible to reach such result.

Comment: Man, I can't thank you enough for helping me out! So I may be wrong but I think the other issue might of been that for each object I had Fire+Smoke as the option. I posted what i have now up above. I essentially want thick smoke bellowing out of it with a roaring fire. Pretty much something like this... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYol3CTmPgM

Also my objects are moving straight up pretty quick so that has an effect on it as well.

Comment: For the Flame part I used Fire+Smoke option too ... I don't know what issue do you mean? I attached blend file if you want to check. Anyway rocket launch usually consist from two Gas sims - one for launch (smoke cluster) and second appended to a rocket engine to keep enough resolution (divisions). It depends what final result should looks like in camera view (some can be achieved by clever camera cuts :) ... If answer solved your issue consider mark as Accepted, so others can see it from main list. Thank you keep site organised. https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour